# How to extend chisel3's bundle to a specific width the value this.getWidth?

Tags: chisel

I'm reinterpreting some chisel3 bundle struct into another bundle.
say,

```scala
val a = Wire(new BundleA)
val b = Wire(new BundleB)
b := a.asTypeOf(b)
```

The two bundle's width is different, I need to extend the `BundleB` to the width of `BundleA` so that the `BundleB` aligns with `BundleA` starting from MSB.

I tried

```scala
class BundleB extends Bundle{
 val sub    = UInt(subfield.W)
 val dummy  = UInt((fullwidth - this.getWidth).W)
}
```

But the width of B is still only `subfield`, not `fullwidth`

So how to construct a bundle of specific width with dummy data and current width?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bug that Chisel isn't erroring here, but `this.getWidth` is causing Chisel to resolve `BundleB` too early, grabbing `sub` as a field but ignoring `dummy`.

There isn't a built-in way to get the "current running width" of the `Bundle` you're constructing, you'd need to do it yourself, something like:

```scala
class BundleB(val subfieldWidth: Int, val fullWidth: Int) extends Bundle {
  val sub   = UInt(subfieldWidth.W)
  private val currentWidth = subfieldWidth // + ... if you have other fields
  val dummy = UInt((fullWidth - subfieldWidth).W)
}
```

Comment: This is the way I'm using. But it's a pain if there are a lot fields in bundle. If there is a way to MSB adjust signals, that should be enough too.

Comment: If I understand correctly and there's just 1 field left unknown, then you could leave it as unknown width `UInt()` and then it will be set by width inference when you drive it from `a`.